# boolean return onAreaTouch method andEngine

Tags: android, boolean, andengine

this is a beginner question. Why the boolean return from this method is same? (true or false has same result)

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                Log.i("testing", "always happen regardless the boolean return");
            }  
            Log.i("asdf", "i thought this line won't happen if return false");
            return false;
        }


@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                Log.i("testing", "always happen regardless the boolean return");
            }  
            Log.i("asdf", "return true, always happen");
            return true;
        }
```

please tell us what's the difference, or which one the right one?

Sorry for bad english

Comment: im confused.. can you please explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning **true** tells the Android that the touch command has been processed.  Therefore, if this code runs, returning true, the Android will not look for any other code that the touch action may run (for example, if there is something underneath the scene).   This can be useful if you have stacked items but only want the touch action to effect the item on top of the stack, or if you want the background to react to a touch but not interfere with the game.